# Is it just me or is the site looking funny right now?

Tags: bug, status-completed

Right now the website's layout looks funny:

[image]

Is this an error I made or did someone rollout an update to do this?

Comment: Reported on meta. [Misplaced navigation bar and question title](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/185720)

Comment: Mine looks slightly better with Adblock off. But LOL as if I'd even run without Adblock for any period of time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I pushed a fix for this to dev. It will be on live server shortly.

Comment: How'd you push something to a dev server if you aren't a staff member?

Comment: @chipperyman573 I am a staff member :)

Comment: Don't staff members have a diamond (♦) next to their name? And my bad, sorry haha.

Answer (score 5):

Its not just you, I see the same issue on SF.

[image]

Comment: Any idea as to when this will be fixed?

Comment: There was an update a few days ago in the SE community, there are a lot of minor bugs everywhere. They will probably repair these in the near future I hope.